# The name Console.WriteLine does not exist in the current context?

Tags: c#, console, console-application

I made a new class and it is saying what I put in the title. I am using system and all the same directives I have used in all my other classes, but this one won't let me for some reason.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AdventureGame
{
    public class BigFella
    {
        Console.WriteLine("hi");
```

Thats literally all my code. But there is a red squiggle under cw.

I didn't try anything, I literally have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: You can't write code directly in a class like this, you need to put it inside a method.

Comment: Trial and (lots of) Errors is a very frustrating way to learn to write software.  Start with some good tutorials and build a reasonable foundation *than* start to code

Answer (score 1):

Your code need a method to call functions.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AdventureGame
{
    public class BigFella
    {

        public void Write()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("hi");
        }
```

and call your class:

```
  BigFella fella = new BigFella();
  fella.Write(); //show hi on console
```